Where to Find Complete Textgreek Conversions from English Letters to Greek with Diacritics?
On the second page of the documentation for textgreek, we find:

However, I could not find within the documentation how to typeset all these letters (let alone diacritics) in a manner analogous to, say, \textgreek{abd} which would produce

or, say \textgreek{>E}, which produces

Where may I obtain a reasonably complete list of textgreek conversions from the English alphabet  (and symbols) to the Greek?
So far, I have not found this on this site nor on the Internet in general.

For Greek text both ancient and modern, I would 1. use LuaLaTeX, 2. use a font that contains the glyphs 2. I use https://www.lexilogos.com/keyboard/greek_ancient.htm  to type them and then copy them over. I also use my yellow sticker method where I have a range of characters, which I copy now and then.

even with pdflatex you do not need to use latin letters, you can use Greek input to typeset Greek if you wish

@yannisl Many thanks for providing the link.
